# Are there problems known about moving comments into chat?

Tags: support

(I'm sorry for producing so much noise about refering in my posts to this question that much)
There actually was a chat room for discussions on this topic.
But this post:

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/251899/88641

Had comments ranging from even pre-chatroom-creation, which where even in the beginning kind of related. Now when I was adding a comment, fredley just added his comment about the chat.

After that I added another comment asking him for also moving that comment I made some seconds after his 'moving'. both comments of me dissappeared.

But I can't find any of the 20 comments in the chat.

So now my question is (since fredley left no comment about the action, I can't see what his intention was):

Are there any known issues by moving comments into chat when the chat allready has been created so there went something wrong?

Or was this an intended action to delete all the comments where some even not were actually discussing? In this case, would the movement of my request to move the comment I made into chat(by given time frame obvisious in no provoking or bad intention) after him pointing to the chat, be kind of disrespectful by just deleting it after I pleased for moving it?

Comment: No there are no known issues. I did not move the comments, I just deleted them since they were just re-statements of the same circle of arguments that is going on *everywhere*.

Comment: @fredley - I'd also like to say that you and the other mods have been doing a stellar job over the last couple of days with this current issue/crisis. Remaining vigilant with the comment pruning/redirection to meta, cooling tempers and not getting frustrated/short with people yourselves must be hard. Not sure if there's a more appropriate place to say it, but: Thanks for doing what must seem like a thankless job sometimes :).

Answer (score 1):

The ability to comment exists as a means of *clarifying information* in a post, with the idea that any clarification and/or interesting and relevant points will be incorporated into the question/answer proper or eventually removed.

From the [privileges page](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) on comments (emphasis mine):

> Comments are **temporary "Post-It" notes** left on a question or answer. [snip] There's no revision history, and when they are deleted they're gone for good.

As there is no revision history for comments and it is possible that they can be removed at any time, it is therefore important not to leave important information sitting in comments:

> You should submit a comment if you want to:
>
> - Request **clarification** from the author;
> - Leave **constructive criticism** that guides the author in improving the post;
> - Add relevant but **minor or transient information** to a post (e.g. a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the
>     question has been updated).

In general, moderators can and will delete any comment that does not align with the above criteria (and sometimes even those that do). There is no onus to 'save' or convert *every* comment to chat. Especially not comments that are:

> - **Suggesting corrections** that don't fundamentally change the meaning of the post; instead, make or suggest an edit;
> - **Answering a question** or providing an alternate solution to an existing answer; instead, post an actual answer (or edit to expand an existing one);
> - **Compliments** which do not add new information ("+1, great answer!"); instead, up-vote it and pay it forward;
> - **Criticisms** which do not add anything constructive ("-1, see previous comments you scallywag!"); instead, down-vote (and provide or up-vote a better answer if appropriate);
> - **Secondary discussion** or debating a controversial point; please use chat instead;
> - **Discussion of community behavior or site policies**; please use meta instead.

In conclusion, if you are concerned that some of your comments contain information that may be lost, then they should probably not be comments, and instead either edited into the post (in the case of added information), or taken to chat (in the case of lengthy discussions about what is right/wrong with a post).